# Can I extend a shower drain with dedicated vent further than 8 feet to the main stack?

Tags: shower, drain, venting

The tub currently has a 1 1/4” drain about 6 feet long to the main stack that will be replaced with a 2 inch pipe. There is a dedicated vent just downstream of the P-trap that has a horizontal run that I understand I would need to replace 2 45s. Considering there is a dedicated vent, is there any configuration that will let me exceed 8 feet from the shower drain to the main stack and vent?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your trap arm is about 4 inches long, up to the first vent.  After that you're vented and  the particular limitation you're thinking of (max trap arm length given pipe size and slope) does not apply; it's not a trap arm any more.

Comment: And if it's a dry vent, which I assume, it doesn't have to be 45 degrees. It can't be *dead* horizontal but needs just enough slope to drain any water that gets into it.

Comment: Jay613, so I can extend the drain to the new shower 28” with the new P trap directly below the shower, and keep the vent where it is? I guess if I could run that dedicated vent near horizontal, and discharge into that 3” toilet arm I could do a center drain in the new shower. That would give me options. I mainly need to make sure it is doable before I knock down a wall to  make the bathroom bigger.

Comment: I would not like to comment any more on what might be possible in a newly configured bathroom.  There are other problems you will face, and unfortunately you can't predict all of them until you knock open the walls and floors.   The fact you HAVE a vent somewhere in the bathroom other than the main stack is a big insurance policy!  It will give you options.  Whether it will let you do exactly what you want, I don't know.   An experienced plumber will see options you won't.  [... 1/2]

Comment: [... 2/2] If the shower will be further from the main stack your biggest worry is vertical space from the top of the shower drain to the ceiling of the floor below.  You need enough vertical space to maintain needed slope, and if there are joists in the way you need to cut through them which may present problems.  A  big fancy shower drain with a built in hair catcher will suck up some of that vertical so if you're challenged, don't buy one.  A linear drain will suck up more height than a center one.  Figure that out, then how to get from the vent to as close as possible to the trap.

Comment: Fair enough. There is about 13” of space from the bottom of the 10” joists to lower bathroom ceiling so no issues there I see with an extra 5/8” fall from what’s there, the pipe from the bath drain is already pretty long and extends below the joists,  The  access port I created allows a view of what’s going on as the photos show. We've seen videos of how nasty linear drains get to not want one. if the vent can stay, I could probably do either left of center drain, new 3x3x3x2 stack T 2” pipe and trap, and a couple 45s should do it.